# Error genexus account (20)

Tags: .net, genexus, cloud

Ayer quise ejecutar la aplicación de GeneXus y me aparece el siguiente error:

> error: GeneXus Account (20): "Please sign the GeneXus Prototyping Cloud Terms and Conditions in order to deploy your application"

Me lleva a un link el cual me aparecen para aceptar los términos, pero una vez que los acepto no pasa más nada. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar este inconveniente? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Lo que describes parece un error de autenticación, como si no fuera capaz de relacionar la cuenta con la que pretendes ejecutar tu aplicación y con la que aceptas los términos. De todas formas he visto que GeneXus tiene una [Community Wiki](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?1755,Wiki+Home,) muy extensa, podrías echar un ojo por ahí y seguro encuentras algo

Comment: Pudiste solucionar ese error? Cómo lo hiciste?

Answer (score 0):

A mi también me estaba pasando este error en la versión TRIAL 18 (Upgrade 7) cuando estaba intentando hacer "RUN" en Run Developer Menu (ejecutar por primera vez la aplicación), lo que hice fue abrir una página de incógnito en chrome loguearme con mi usuario y contraseña de Genexus, volver a darle RUN, y volver a aceptar los términos y condiciones pero desde el navegador de incognito y me permitió avanzar en la creación de la Base de Datos.